# Why does the Facebook Graph API for albums return images with height & width of 0?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, photos

For a non-trivial number of user photos, I am getting data from the Graph API data that looks like this: (Python dict after parsing using json module)

```
{u'created_time': u'2012-04-01T19:02:02+0000',
 u'from': {u'id': u'xxxxxxx', u'name': u'xxxxx'},
 u'icon': u'https://s-static.ak.facebook.com/rsrc.php/v1/xxxx',
 u'id': u'xxxxxxx',
 u'images': [{u'height': 0, u'width': 0},
             {u'height': 0, u'width': 0},
             {u'height': 0, u'width': 0},
             {u'height': 0, u'width': 0}],
 u'link': u'http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=xxxxx&set=a.xxxxx&type=1',
 u'updated_time': u'2012-04-01T19:02:02+0000'}
```

By contrast, good data looks like this (from the same album):

```
 {u'created_time': u'2008-10-21T17:58:31+0000',
  u'from': {u'id': u'xxxxxxx', u'name': u'xxxxxxxx'},
  u'height': 453,
  u'icon': u'https://s-static.ak.facebook.com/rsrc.php/v1/xxxx',
  u'id': u'xxxxxxxx',
  u'images': [{u'height': 453,
               u'source': u'https://fbcdn-sphotos-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/xxxxxx.jpg',
               u'width': 592},
              {u'height': 137,
               u'source': u'https://fbcdn-photos-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/xxxxxx.jpg',
               u'width': 180},
              {u'height': 99,
               u'source': u'https://fbcdn-photos-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/xxxxxx.jpg',
               u'width': 130},
              {u'height': 57,
               u'source': u'https://fbcdn-photos-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/xxxxxx.jpg',               
               u'width': 75}],
  u'link': u'http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=xxxxxxx&set=a.xxxxxxxx&type=1',
  u'picture': u'https://fbcdn-photos-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/xxxxxxx.jpg',
  u'position': 123,
  u'source': u'https://fbcdn-sphotos-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/xxxxxxx.jpg',
  u'updated_time': u'2011-03-31T09:15:08+0000',
  u'width': 592}
```

What's that all about?  Does it mean that the photo was deleted?  Or is it a bug on FB's side?